# How do we verify that a phone call is going through WiFi?

Tags: wi-fi, calls

## How do we verify that a phone call is going through WiFi?

I am hoping that there is some special little icon like this one:

[image]

Cricket wireless is my provider and my phone is a Motorola moto g7 SUPRA.

My carrier does support WiFi calling. I spent an hour on the phone with them trying to answer the question the above question. The device also supports WiFi calling and reports that WiFi calling has been correctly activated

Our local cell towers went down today so I wanted to have another way to make phone calls that did not depend on an active cell tower. I set up WiFi calling on my phone and it confirmed that it was set up correctly and enabled. The WiFi also indicated that it was connected. It is a very strong connection because it is only ten feet way and direct line-of-sight.

After I did this I still experienced the same issues that I had because of the bad cell tower. This would seem to indicate that the phone calls were not going through WiFi.

Comment: Most phones will actually say "WiFi Call" or something similar on the dialer screen while in call, I know my Pixel does.

Comment: @beeshyams Yes my carrier supports this I spent an hour on the phone with them trying to answer the question the above question. The device supports this and the device reports that WiFi calling has been correctly activated.

Answer (score 1):

> You can test whether Wi-Fi calling is working by activating Airplane
> mode, then turning just Wi-Fi back on, and connecting to your home
> Wi-Fi network. The icon should appear in your notification bar and
> you’ll be able to make or receive calls. [Testing WiFi Phone
> Calling](https://www.digitaltrends.com/mobile/wi-fi-calling-guide/#:%7E:text=You%20can%20test%20whether%20Wi,to%20make%20or%20receive%20calls)

I tried this and it worked. I turned my WiFi router off and because I was still in airplane mode phone calls did not work. This proves that the above advice is correct.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using a Pixel 3 XL, I've not "seen" any top menu icon or place to know if my phone is using 802.11 protocols for a call.

The only way I know to easily force a TCP/IP 802.11 protocol is to use Google Hangouts. You can dial any phone number from there for free.

I have 2 "Google Phone Numbers" but I've not seen/dug for the information on how to receive calls on those numbers.